# Liquid Syntax Not Evaluating Using Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I followed the following instructions to create a new Jekyll website.

```
gem install bundler jekyll

  jekyll new my-awesome-site

  cd my-awesome-site

  bundle exec jekyll serve

# => Now browse to http://localhost:4000
```

This all works fine. Now, I want to inject some Liquid syntax so I added the following in my HTML page.

```
<h2 class="post-list-heading">Posts</h2>
    <ul class="post-list"><li><span class="post-meta">Jan 16, 2020</span>
        <h3>
          {{ page.title }}
          <a class="post-link" href="/jekyll/update/2020/01/16/welcome-to-jekyll.html">
            Welcome to Jekyll!
          </a>
        </h3></li></ul>
```

Now, when I run the page, I don't see the page.title being evaluating. I see the following result.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to modify a file from **_site** folder ? This folder contains generated site, it is not processed anymore. You have to modify sources, logically **_layouts/post.html** which is already outputting your `page.title`.

Comment: I am confused. Where should I write {{page.title}} syntax. I wrote it in the file contained in _posts and got the same result.

Comment: I had to create layouts directory. Got it fixed.